# Top bars overlapping each other

Tags: bug, design, top-bar

Can't see the icons at the top.

Firefox on Linux

[image]

Comment: VTR as this addresses the issue that the top bar is mostly covered by… well… the other top bar. The horizontal position of the many bars is irrelevant here.

Comment: @dessert It is the same problem, just depends on how zoomed the page is, the further you zoom out, the further left the bar moves.